# how to generate report and save it to file using pl/sql oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to generate report and save it to file using pl/sql oracle?

Answer (score 4):

From your post it's unclear what report and from what data sources you want to generate. Concerning writing to a file from PL/SQL [utl_file](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#ARPLS069) package can help, but bear in mind that file will be written to a server directory.

Answer (score 1):

[DBMS_OUTPUT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA) can be used to generate shorter reports (there is a maximum size that the generated output can be) that can be saved on the client side.